# The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider

Tags: c#, cryptography, data-protection, .net-core-2.1

I am using Data Protection APIs from .NetCore, while unprotecting payload using DangerousUnprotect() from IPersistedDataProtector, I am getting said error message.

I have created a single instance of protector using CreateProtector("purpose") of IDataProtectionProvider and using it in different APIs to protect() & unprotect() data. Both APIs work fine for all requests made, however after revocation of a key, I am casting dataProtector to IPersistedDataProtector and then it keeps on throwing an error "The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider."

I understand that the message is valid by code point of view but could not understand what is causing it to throw. I am using the same application name and purpose string.

I have compared instances of protector as well and they are equal with the same data protection provider instance. Can someone please advise on how can this be traced?

target package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection(2.1.1)

Also visited issues but do not see any fix/relevant information to this.

```cs
// inside .ctor
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("ApplicationName");


var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
this.dPProvider = serviceProvider.GetDataProtectionProvider();
this.protector = this.dPProvider.CreateProtector("purpose");
```

```cs
public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            try
            {
                return this.protector.Unprotect(cipherText);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var persistedProtector = this.protector as IPersistedDataProtector;
                if (persistedProtector == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Protector cannot be null. Also {exception.Message}");
                }
// exception is thrown at below line.
                var unprotectedPayload = persistedProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText), true, out var requiresMigration, out var wasRevoked);
                if (wasRevoked)
                {
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unprotectedPayload);
                }

                throw new CryptographicException($"Invalid operation. Also {exception.Message}", exception);
            }
        }
```

stacktrace :    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)

Comment: Issue was with encoder, please [refer](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8776) for more details and below change fixed.
```csharp
var unprotectedPayload = persistedProtector.DangerousUnprotect(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(encryptedWithRevokedKey), true, out var migrate, out var revoked);
```